# Xinerama causes windows to maximize across both monitors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-10.04, xinerama

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Debian Gnome, windows are maximizing over multiple monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/371096/in-debian-gnome-windows-are-maximizing-over-multiple-monitors)

After I installed Xinerama whenever I maximize a window it spreads the window across both of my monitors. This doesn't work well for me since the monitors are not the same size nor at the same height. How can I make windows just maximize up to the window that they're on?